# Programmatically suspending an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, autoscaling

I have a server that has logic evaluating when it needs to scale up or scale down the back end instances of a given web service.
The trouble is I am unsure as of how exactly I am to programmatically send commands to my EC2 console instructing it to suspend or activate one of the back up services.

I am aware that I can simply have a backup scripted to start and stop at certain times,however ideally I want my web service instances to start/stop in response to certain events such as increased demand.

Comment: Did you look at leveraging auto scaling rather than rolling your own solution? https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ You can scale based on cloudwatch metrics so you have a ton of flexibility.

Comment: Can you please share little bit more about how you have done scaling programmatically ? I've such requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment I suggest you take a look at [autoscaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) -- it sounds perfect for your use-case. Scaling up in response to increased demand and scaling down when idle is exactly what it was designed for.

You can use the API to spawn and terminate instances if needed though:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html